# Рисование стен three js

Tags: three.js

Суть в создании системы, которая бы позволяла рисовать стены в проекциях xz. У меня уже есть идея, касательно реализации данной системы, к примеру брать начальную точку и конечную точку (два клика мыши), затем вычислять серединную точку отрезка и создавать там геометрию, длиной которой будет длина отрезка (вычисляется по формуле Пифагора). Хотелось бы услышать идеи и мнение других, касательно реализации данной системы (как бы можно было бы её упростить или выстроить альтернативу).

Comment: Слишком широкое определение задачи. Обычно достаточно легко получив сегмент в 2D добавить пару точек на нужной высоте Z и построить пару треугольников для получения стенки.

Comment: @Kromster был бы рад, если б был бы пример реализации в коде, так сказать, чтобы можно было разобраться на практике

Comment: А что если открыть виндовый обыкновенный web builder нарисовать и экспортировать а потом посмотреть как сделан код

Comment: @Kromster а потом выяснится, что стена должна быть не просто тонким плэйном, а иметь ненулевую толщину, а потом еще и изгибаться в нескольких местах так, чтобы сегменты в стыках не выпирали друг из-под друга ) а еще Т-образные стыки стен есть, или под углом (что еще веселее).

Comment: @Leobuildru _"вычисляется по формуле Пифагора"_ - для этого есть метод `.distanceTo()` у объекта `Vector3`

Comment: @Kromster а что если создавать стену из plane, чтобы был плавный переход между стенами, чтобы была возможность менять угол поворота одной из сторон, возможно ли такое? При том вставляя функцию draganddrop перемещения точек из которых вырастают стены

Comment: Возможно практически все! )